# OCaml: how to use batteries and ppx_deriving.* together?

Tags: ocaml, ppx

Currently I'm trying to use `Batteries` with `ppx_deriving.show` or something similar.
I am wondering how to use them together usefully.

To create dumping functions, I feel ppx_deriving.show is useful.
But I have a little bit troubles using them together like the followings.

```
open Batteries
type t = { a: (int,int) Map.t }
[@@deriving show]
```

Now `Map.pp` is not defined, so it can't be compiled.

My adhoc fix is that I create `module Map` which include `Batteries.Map` and define function `pp`.

```
open Batteries
module Map = struct
  include Map
  let pp f g fmt t = ... (* create dump function by man hand *)
end

type t = { a: (int,int) Map.t }
[@@deriving show]
```

It works, but it is painful for me to adapt all of data structures...
`Core` with `ppx_deriving.sexp` is an alternative choice, but I prefer `Batteries` with `ppx_deriving.show`.
Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Comment: All things considered, pretty printing raw data structures might not be useful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fix is the right way.  If you want to use deriving for data types `M.t` declared without `[@@deriving]`, you have to give its methods such as `M.pp` for `show` by yourself:

```
module M = struct
  include M
  let pp = ... (* code for pretty-printing M.t *)
end
```

There is a way to partially automate this:

```
module M = struct
  include M
  type t = M.t = ... (* the same type definition of M.t *)
    [@@deriving show]
end
```

It generates `M.pp` for type `t` using `deriving`.

With `ppx_import`, you can avoid copy-and-pasting of the definition:

```
module M = struct
  include M
  type t = [%import: M.t]
    [@@deriving show]
end
```

This should be expanded to the former code.

As you have found out, deriving `show` of `Map.t` is not really useful though: normally you do not want to see the binary tree representation of `Map.t` unless you are debugging `Map` module itself.